# Beam SlidingWindows: Not duplicating elements as expected

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using apache beam on Google Cloud Dataflow, and I'm trying to use a sliding window to output duplicate elements every 5 seconds, In preparation for a join.

```
def logger_helper(r):
    logging.getLogger().info(r)
    return r

        window = (
            records
            | beam.Map(lambda r: (r['key'], r))
            | "Page View Window " >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.SlidingWindows(900, 5))
            | "Print Page View Window" >> beam.Map(lambda r: logger_helper(r))
        )
```

What I expected: a key would be logged every 5 seconds for 900 seconds (15 min)
However, I only see a key logged once and never again. How do I get the same key to show up every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windowing is not applied. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-constraints)

> Window grouping occurs on an as-needed basis. If you set a windowing
> function using the Window transform, each element is assigned to a
> window, **but the windows are not considered until GroupByKey or Combine**
> aggregates across a window and key.

So try adding a `GroupByKey` or `Combine` step to your pipeline (before the print).